# Chromedriver doesn't opens link a new tab or window , instead the expected link is opened in current tab/window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is the code i have tried to handle window but the url for opens in the tab of google.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/ish/chromedriver");    

WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("http://google.com");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"n");
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    for(String windowHandle:driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
    }
    driver.get("http://fb.com");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the iteration over the window handles you are switching to both of them. The last switch returns the focus to the first window and the link is getting opened there.

You should do the switch only to the new window

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/ish/chromedriver");    

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("http://google.com");

String firstWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"n");
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    for(String windowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        if (!windowHandle.equals(firstWindowHandle)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
        }
    }
    driver.get("http://fb.com");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: still not working .. same problem .. not opening the window.

Answer (score 0):

Driver is opening in same window, because for loop is switching old handle

Code probably should look like this below

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/ish/chromedriver");    

WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("http://google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"n");
        String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            for(String windowHandle:driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                if(!currentHandle.equals(windowHandle)){
                   driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
                   break;
                }
            }
            driver.get("http://fb.com");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```